# Reading a line from a file at a specific point

Tags: c, printf, malloc, scanf

so Im writing a code to get scanf a text file and return a format text message log. I'm stuck wondering how to scan strings from file at a certain point and print every string beyond that point E.X When the file scans the line 
"332982000 2055552002 2055551001 7 Mr Webb, can I ask you a question?" I scan the first 4 numbers as integers and scan the rest of the written text into an char array starting at "Mr. Webb".

I tried using a for loop with fscanf to scan into an array but it didnt work. I was also thinking I could use malloc just to save space but I dont know what to put in the sizeof argument. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
int posix;
int phone1;
int phone2;
int textsize;
int val, val2;
char line[256];
char text[3000];
int len=strlen(line);
int i=0;

printf("\n\nTime                           %s                           %s", argv[2], argv[3]);
printf("\n======================================================================================\n\n\n");

FILE* textfile= fopen(argv[1],"r");

fscanf(textfile, "%d %d %d %d %s", &posix, &phone1, &phone2, &textsize, text);

while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), textfile) ) { 

    val= atoi(argv[2]);
    val2=atoi(argv[3]);

    if ( (val==phone1) && (val2==phone2) ) {
        printf(" %s ", text); //only prints Mr
        text=(char*)malloc(sizeof())//tried malloc but not too sure how to use it correctly
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) { //tried using for loop here didnt work. 
          fscanf("%s", text);
          }

        sortText(phone1, phone2, textsize, text);
        //readableTime(posix);
         }
```

else if ( (val2==phone1) && (val==phone2) ) {
            printf(" %s ", text);

```
        sortText(phone1, phone2, textsize, text);
        //readableTime(posix);
         }


fscanf(textfile, "%d %d %d %d %s", &posix, &phone1, &phone2, &textsize, text);
```

}

```
fclose(textfile);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The `%s` directive skips leading whitespace and scans a *whitespace-delimited* string.  If you want to scan to the end of the line, then you can use `" %[^\n]"` -- the leading space character causes leading whitespace to be skipped, which unlike `%s`, `%[` does not do automatically, and the contents of the brackets specify which characters to accept (anything other than newline in this case).  Do note that unless you specify a field width, there is a risk of overrunning the bounds of the `text` array.

Answer (score 1):

At first, read the entire file into a malloc'd char array. The fseek and ftell give you the file size:

```
// C99
FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r");
size_t filesize;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
filesize = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char *filetext = malloc(filesize + 1);
fread(filetext, 1, filesize, fp);
filetext[filesize] = 0;
```

Then use a buffer for a single line with the size of the entire file so you surely have enough size. sscanf() can be used to read stuff from a string.

```
int readbytes;

for(int i=0; i < filesize; i+=readbytes) {
    char line[filesize];
    int posix, phone1, phone2, textsize;

    if(EOF == sscanf(
        &filetext[i], "%d%d%d%d%[^\n]%n", &posix, &phone1,
        &phone2, &textsize, line, &readbytes))
    {
        break;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d %d '%s' %d\n", posix, phone1, phone2, textsize, line, readbytes);
}
```

The format specifier '%[^\n]' means: every character until the next newline character. The format specifier '%n' gives you the number of bytes that have been read with this sscanf call so far, effectively your line size, that you can use to advance the iterator.

Comment: Well okay I added some extra unnecessary complexity here: you don't have to load the entire file at first. You can do this with fscanf as well instead of sscanf. But at least it is beneficial to know the filesize in advance.